# How to use moment-timezone for mapping with C# TimeZoneInfo?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, moment-timezone

I need to make illusion of working in the selected by the user timezone. The problem that server and client code are stick to javascript date. So to achieve the requirement I have made mannualy mapping from utc to the date on the client side:

```
dateToServer(date) {
    const momentDate = moment(date);
    let serverDate = null;
    if (momentDate.isValid() && date) {
        const browserUtcOffset = momentDate.utcOffset();
        serverDate = momentDate
            .utc()
            .subtract(this.clientTimeZoneOffset, 'minutes')
            .add(browserUtcOffset, 'minutes')
            .toDate();
    }
    return serverDate;
}


dateToClient(date) {
    const momentDate = moment(date);
    let uiDate = null;
    if (momentDate.isValid() && date) {
        const browserUtcOffset = momentDate.utcOffset();
        uiDate = momentDate
            .utc()
            .subtract(browserUtcOffset, 'minutes')
            .add(this.clientTimeZoneOffset, 'minutes')
            .toDate();
    }
    return uiDate;
}
```

I'm adding/subtracting the browserUtcOffset, because it is adding/subtracting automatically by browser when the date is go between server and client.

It was working well, but this solution is missing handling of the DST. I'd like to check is DST active for the date and then add DST offset if need.

Here C# code, that can do this:

```
        string timeZone = "Central Standard Time";
        TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 3, 14);
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes); // -360
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(date).TotalMinutes); // -300
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(date)); // true
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.DaylightName);
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
```

I have found the `isDST` in the momentjs, and when I have my windows local timezone to CST and check `moment([2011, 2, 14]).isDST();` in browser console I see the true. How you can see the `isDST` is depends on the browser local time.

Next step try to use moment-timezone to do smth like I have done in C#. Unfortunately I don't understand how to achieve this. The first problem that as start point I have: `UTC time`, `Base offset(-360 in C# sample)`, `timezone name: Central Standard Time`, but timezones in the moment-timezone are different.

`moment.tz.names().map(name => moment.tz.zone(name)).filter(zone => zone.abbrs.find(abbr => abbr === 'CST') != null)` this code returns 68 timezones.
[image]

Why there each of them have many abbrs? What mean untils? All I want to check if UTC time in the selected timezone, which is "Central Standard Time", the daylight saving day active. See C# sample one more time :)

```
        string timeZone = "Central Standard Time";
        TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 3, 14);
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes); //-360
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(date).TotalMinutes); //-300
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(date)); //true, I have checked is daylightsavingtime for the date
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.DaylightName);
        Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
```

The application has been written on the angularjs 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check please the [answer of Matt Johnson for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54042889/6382078). It was very usefull for me.**

**Vocabulary**

- UI date - the date that user see on the html date input when
  selecting the date. UI date is the native js date.
- Server date - the UTC date that is stored in the
  database.
- timezone id - string, that identified the timezone. They are different for windows(.net), IANA(javascript) and rails conventions.

**Problem**

The main problem f.e. when a man logged in on the PC which is located in the timezone +3, but setting for his account is -6. The angularjs and kendo is using on the project and the kendo time is working only with native js date. And native js date is always in the browser timezone, for this example +3. But I should setup the stuff like it in -6. F.e. example user has selected time 07:00, the UTC will be 04:00 (07:00 - 3), but as for his account the timezone is -6, the utc should be 13:00 (07:00 + 6). And this conversations are applied automatically when we converting native js date(UI date) to UTC and backward.  So decision to count the offset on the server and get rid off browser timezone offset: `utcTime = UItime + browserOffset - clientTimezoneBaseOffset - daylightSavingTimeOffset`.
However there is problem when need to get UI time back, f.e. today 06.06.2014 and the DST is true for this date, but when we are getting 03.03.2014 date from server we don't know if the DST was active for 03.03.2014.

**Answer**

In project on the server the .net, so in database the window's timezone IDs are stored. I have done it the next way: count on server DST for date ranges in the range from minimum date on the server and save on the client in the local storage. I like that in this case 
the server is one source of truth, so the calculations can be performed on any client without manipulating the timezones. And no need to convert between IANA, Windows and rails timezones. But also there is a problem: need to precalculate DST in range from `DateTime.MinValue` to `DateTime.MaxValue`, currently to speed up I'm calculating DST for range from `01.01.2000` to `DateTime.Now` - it is enough when converting value from database to UI, because in database the min date is on the 2008 year, but is not enough for html input, because user can select value greater than `DateTime.Now` and lower then `01.01.2000`. To fix it I'm, planning with use of [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) send to client the `IANATimezoneId`, and for cases when provided date(UI or server) is not in the range `[01.01.2000, DateTime.Now]` belong on the `moment.utc(date).tz(IANATimezoneId).isDST()`.

**This is new code on the server side**

```
    private class DaylightSavingTimeDescriptor
    {
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool IsDaylightSavingTime { get; set; }
    }

    private string GetDaylightSavingTimeDescriptorsJson(string timeZone)
    {
        string daylightSaveingTimeDescriptorsJson = String.Empty;
        if(timeZone != null)
        {
            List<DaylightSavingTimeDescriptor> dstList = new List<DaylightSavingTimeDescriptor>();
            TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
            DateTime dateIterator = startDate;
            bool isDST = timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(startDate);
            while (dateIterator < DateTime.Now)
            {
                bool currDST = timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateIterator);
                if (isDST != currDST)
                {
                    dstList.Add(new DaylightSavingTimeDescriptor()
                    {
                        EndTime = dateIterator.AddDays(-1),
                        IsDaylightSavingTime = isDST,
                        StartTime = startDate
                    });
                    startDate = dateIterator;
                    isDST = currDST;
                }
                dateIterator = dateIterator.AddDays(1);
            }

            daylightSaveingTimeDescriptorsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dstList);
        }
        return daylightSaveingTimeDescriptorsJson;
    }
```

**And this is modified dateToServer, dateToClient on client side**

```
export default class DateService{
constructor (authService) {
    const authData = authService.getAuthData();
    this.clientTimeZoneOffset = Number(authData.timeZoneOffset);
    this.daylightSavingTimeRanges = authData.daylightSavingTimeRanges ? JSON.parse(authData.daylightSavingTimeRanges) : [];
}

getDaylightSavingTimeMinutesOffset(utcDate) {
    const dstRange = this.daylightSavingTimeRanges.find(range => {
        const momentStart = moment(range.startTime).utc();
        const momentEnd = moment(range.endTime).utc();
        const momentDate = moment(utcDate).utc();
        return momentStart.isBefore(momentDate) && momentEnd.isAfter(momentDate);
    });
    const isDaylightSavingTime = dstRange ? dstRange.isDaylightSavingTime : false;
    return isDaylightSavingTime ? '60' : 0;
}

dateToClient(date) {
    const momentDate = moment(date);
    let uiDate = null;
    if (momentDate.isValid() && date) {
        const browserUtcOffset = momentDate.utcOffset();
        uiDate = momentDate
            .utc()
            .subtract(browserUtcOffset, 'minutes')
            .add(this.clientTimeZoneOffset, 'minutes')
            .add(this.getDaylightSavingTimeMinutesOffset(momentDate.utc()), 'minutes')
            .toDate();
    }
    return uiDate;
}

dateToServer(date) {
    const momentDate = moment(date);
    let serverDate = null;
    if (momentDate.isValid() && date) {
        const browserUtcOffset = momentDate.utcOffset();
        serverDate = momentDate
            .utc()
            .subtract(this.clientTimeZoneOffset, 'minutes')
            .add(browserUtcOffset, 'minutes')
            .subtract(this.getDaylightSavingTimeMinutesOffset(momentDate.utc()), 'minutes')
            .toDate();
    }
    return serverDate;
}
}
```

**PS**

I want to get rid off offsets and use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) on the client and [timezone converter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) on the server, but it will be later if customer ask, because I have never tried it before and I'm not sure that it will be working well, and current solution is working. Also the offsets anyway will be used for dateinputs components (angularjs), because they are using kendo-dateinput which ng-model is JS Date in browser local time, but I'm providing another timezone so need to transformations inside component.

**PPS Best solution from my point of view, if [timezone converter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) and [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) will be working as expected**

Anyway the whole app is operating the JS Date, so when user in Moscow with America in profile selects the datetime in kendo-input, or see setup kendo-scheduler, or display the date in the kendo-table, I need to manipulate with offsets. But instead of passing directly the client offset, I'm planning to pass IANA timezone id from the server with help of [timezone converter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) and get the offset I need directly from [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: There are still lots of problems with this.  Ultimately, the problem you're facing (like many others) is that Kendo UI's DatePicker control *only* works with `Date` objects, and thus it expects the user is *only* picking a date/time for their own local time zone.  There are [other datepickers out there](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) that do not have this problem.  BTW, this is the same reason that the [`value` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value) of `HTML Input type=date` is a *string* rather than a `Date` object.

Comment: Just some of the problems you may face with the approach you gave: 1) Many time zones have transitions due to changes in their *standard time*, not just DST.  2) Not all DST transitions are 60 minutes (there's one that's 30).  3) If a transition exists in the local time zone, but is different or nonexistent in the target one, your user won't be able to pick a time that falls into a forward gap in the local (ex: local DST moves the clocks forward from 2:00 to 3:00, user can't pick 2:30 even though the target time zone still has it).

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

- The `Date` object in JavaScript tracks a specific UTC-based point in time.  You can see that timestamp with a call to `.valueOf()` or `.getTime()`.  It is only certain functions and constructor parameters that work with the local time zone (such as `.toString()`).  That local time zone is applied at the time the function is called.  One cannot substitute a different time zone (except in the options object passed to `toLocaleString`).  Thus, the `Date` object ***can not*** be converted from one time zone to another.  Because your two functions both take in a `Date` object and return a `Date` object, all you are doing in the middle is *picking a different point in time*.  This is also seen inside the function where you use the `add` and `subtract` methods of Moment.  They manipulate the represented point in time - they do not change the time zone.
- By passing `this.clientTimeZoneOffset`, You appear to have conflated a time zone with a time zone offset.  These are separate concepts, as a time zone may go through multiple different offsets, due to DST but also due to changes in standard time, where they have occurred in history.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  It is not useful to pass just the client's offset, as that offset only applies to a single point in time.  You cannot use it for time zone conversions, because it doesn't tell you anything about which offsets are used for other points in time.
- Instead, pass a time zone identifier.  On Windows in .NET, these look like `"Central Standard Time"` (representing both standard and daylight time despite the name), and in JavaScript and most other operating systems, IANA time zone names are used.  They look like `"America/Chicago"`.  This is also covered in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- If your .NET code is using Windows identifiers, you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to convert from Windows to IANA, then send that string to the browser as the time zone.
- With Moment-Timezone, you can simply check the DST like so:

  ```
  moment.tz([2011, 2, 14], 'America/Chicago').isDST()
  ```

  Again, you should be using [IANA time zone IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), and TimeZoneConverter can provide them if you're using Windows time zones server-side.
- You *could* consider using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) on the server-side, with its TZDB time zone provider.  That would allow you to use IANA time zones on both sides.  This is also the case with `TimeZoneInfo` when run on .NET Core on Linux or Mac OSX.
- The reason you see so many entries when you searched for abbreviations with `CST` is that time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.  You may have meant US Central Standard Time, but you might also have meant Cuba Standard Time or China Standard Time, or a variety of other places that use that abbreviation.
- Regarding the `untils` array, you generally don't need to concern yourself with that.  It is part of the internal data that Moment-Timezone uses to pick the correct point in time for choosing a time zone offset and abbreviation.
- You said at the end, something slightly different:

  > All I want to check if UTC time in the selected timezone, which is "Central Standard Time", the daylight saving day active.

  The example I gave earlier assumed you were starting with that time zone's local time.  If you're starting with the UTC time, then it's like this:

  ```
  moment.utc([2011, 2, 14]).tz('America/Chicago').isDST()
  ```

  Of course, you can pass various other supported inputs where I pass the array.  The [Moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) can help you with available options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't known about IANA and windows timezones. The main problem f.e. when a man logged in on the PC which is located in the timezone +3, but setting for his account is -6. The angularjs and kendo is using on the project and the kendo time is working only with native js date. And native js date is always in the browser timezone, for this example +3. But I should setup the stuff like it in -6. So decision to count the offset on the server and get rid off browser timezont offset: `utcTime = UItime + browserOffset - clientTimezoneBaseOffset - daylightSavingTimeOffset`

Comment: However there is problem when need to get UI time back, f.e. today 06.06.2014 and the DST is true for this date, but when we are getting 03.03.2014 date from server we don't know if the DST was active for 03.03.2014.

Comment: Check my answer for my solution. I think next time I should start the question from the problem :)